# How to retrieve record from database using Linq in mvc architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have one table with fields `group name`,`description` and `isactive(boolean datatype)`.
I want to write a `Linq` query which select all records whose status is true. I tried something like this. but it's giving error.

```
List<tm_grp_group> tm = db.tm_grp_group.Where(x => x.grp_isactive.Equals(true));
return Json(tm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Try this: `var tm = db.tm_grp_group.Where(x => x.grp_isactive).ToList()`

Comment: What is error pls give more explanation.

Comment: Check my answer i think you have same error  @Niranjan godbole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question absouletly same this [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/where-boolean-equals-true) pls try this ways:

```
List<tm_grp_group> tm = db.tm_grp_group.Where(x => x.grp_isactive== true).ToList();
```

or

```
List<tm_grp_group> tm = db.tm_grp_group.Where(x => x.grp_isactive).ToList();
```